# Is it possible to dynamically generate a Google Doc from php web app?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

The title pretty much sums it up. I've looked in the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk

But can't find an answer to this question. I think I understand that my app could create a new file in an user's Drive, but what I want to do is to generate a new Google Doc file and populate it with content that comes from my app.

Comment: What's the difference between "create a new file in a user's drive" and "generate a new Google Doc file and populae it with content from my app"? Where do you think the new file in the user's drive gets its contents?

Comment: I just see nowhere how to fill it with content (text, tables, etc.) so I felt like it would create a file with predefined content or empty.

Comment: See the section on uploading files https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

Comment: If I get it well I have to populate the Google Doc by converting either a Word, OpenDoc, HTML, RTF or plain text. Since I will be generating from a web app, I would convert from a HTML page. I'll need to play with headers, footers, margins, etc. Do you think I'll be able to do so or it's not possible to be that precise?

Comment: I'm sure you can upload most file types. If you want to upload HTML, use `'mimeType' => 'text/html'`

Comment: Yep, that I get it, but I'm wondering if I'll be able to create headers and footers in my Google Doc using a HTML files... or even play with margins

Comment: Can you do it interactively from the web interface? If you can, then you should be able to do the same thing from the API.

Comment: You're right I'll test it this way, thanks.

Comment: Bramar, your assumption is incorrect. there is no api yet for a google doc, except from apps script.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive API is deigned to allow you to access files on [Google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk).  You can list files, upload and download them.   You basically have file system access.

The Google Drive API does not have the power to allow you to edit the file itself. Depending upon the type of file lets say its a Google doc.  You would have to download the file make your changes and upload it again.  This could of course be done using PHP : [php quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php)  [Uploading files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) [downloading files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

If the file is a Google sheet then you can go though the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) which will allow you to programmaticly edit a google sheet without having to download the file itself.

Comment: Ok but I need the Google doc file to be edited programmaticaly with php or javascript. Would that be possible? I would create a new Google doc file, download it, edit it programmaticaly with my web app and then upload it again.

Comment: You will have to research that I am not sure if you can edit a doc file with php you would have to export it to Microsoft doc format when you download it the up load it again converting it back to Google doc.

Comment: So I should rather create a Microsoft Word file, edit it with PHP and then upload it as a Google doc. If so, do you know a good way to create Microsoft doc files with php app and edit it (header, footer, images, margins, etc.)?

Comment: No sorry I didn't you may want to research that and open a new question if you have any issues.